# PHP replace tag ant contents

Tags: php

Searched trough all Stackoverflow, but can’t find suitable regex. I have html with a lot of tags, and have a piece of code that I need to find and remove:

```
<p>[spoiler id=7]</p>
```

At this moment I only can replace spoiler id tag with this regex:

```
"/\[spoiler id=(.*?)]/"
```

Comment: what about str_replace() function from php? Perhaps will be easier for you instead of regular expressions

Comment: I've assumed that the `<p>` tags were part of your data and not just format for the question and you aren't really using fancy quotes in PHP code. Please feel free to revert my edit if I got something wrong.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, :( my answer becomes irrelevant with them

Answer (score 1):

RegExp is `/\[spoiler\s+id=\d+\]/`

Key is escaping of control characters(square brakes).
`\s+` - any spaces
`\d+` - any digits

It is static in common, feel free to add static text(paragraph tags)..

`'#<p>\s*\[spoiler\s+id=\d+\]\s*</p>#'`

[Demonstration](https://3v4l.org/HJ9rg)

Comment: Your regex is not valid :/

Comment: Why? I've add simple demo. Check it.